# react-native-firebase unable to handle notification click_action to navigate to notification screen

Tags: android, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-firebase, react-native-fcm

i'm using this react-native-firebase and react-navigation for navigating and i can push notification from server or console successfully whether its in foreground or background but i swear the documentation is not pretty clear how to open notification and navigate to the notification screen it belongs to. these are my onMessage codes.

```
 firebase.messaging().onMessage((payload) => {

     if(!payload.opened_from_tray){
      firebase.messaging().createLocalNotification({
        title: payload.title,
        body: payload.body,
        show_in_foreground: true,
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        local_notification: "true",
        priority: "high",
        click_action:"ACTION",
        opened_from_tray: true,
      })
     }


  });
```

i'm running the version 3.2.2 of react-native-firebase

Comment: https://medium.com/react-native-training/deep-linking-your-react-native-app-d87c39a1ad5e Did you look this already?

Comment: @Bright Lee thx for quick reply let me look into it

Comment: @Bright Lee if understand well Deep linking is used to link ur app with incoming url from websites or external app and in that article they didn't talked about notifications I think there is how you can handle click_actions in those library such as React-native-firebase or React-native-fcm but their documentation sucks

Comment: @dannykush Did you found a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

right now i am not using createLocalNotification(), so am able to receive a notification when my app is closed using getInitialNotification(), :)

```
firebase.messaging().getInitialNotification()
    .then(payload => {
      console.log(payload);
      if(payload.slug != undefined){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('notification',{slug:payload.slug});
      }else{

      }
    });
```

i hope it solves your issue too

Comment: Hello, can you check this question please @frontendkiller
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57171787/navigate-to-screen-after-opening-a-notification