# Cloud Messaging Push Notification click action

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have been looking all over for a guide on how to access Custom data like keys and values in Firebase Cloud Messaging to do a click action for. My goal is to be able to target a specific click action for the notifications I send to my app when the notification is clicked.

How can this be done? I am sending notifications from the Firebase Cloud Messaging console. [I saw a post here, but it did not solve my issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48319357/react-native-firebase-unable-to-handle-notification-click-action-to-navigate-to)

I am using the following libraries:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';
import type { Notification, NotificationOpen } from 'react-native-firebase';
```

This is what I use to target background opens or closed app opens.

```
  /*
  * If your app is in background, you can listen for when a notification is clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
  * */
  this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;

      Get custom key values for click action here and use it to navigate. 

      navigate(key_action??)
  });

  /*
  * If your app is closed, you can check if it was opened by a notification being clicked / tapped / opened as follows:
  * */
  const notificationOpen = await firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification();
  if (notificationOpen) {
      const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
      const { title, body } = notificationOpen.notification;
      navigate(key_action??)
  }
```

Comment: which library are you using to handle push notifications?

Comment: @HaiderAli I am using the Firebase Cloud Messaging console to send notifications, and I am using react-native-firebase to handle the push notifications.